# How do I print something to an output file?

Tags: java, file, input

Specifically speaking, I have managed to create (perhaps) a program that reads in a file and puts an indent at the beginning of each paragraph. Problem is, before I had the character counter printing to the output file, and now I have absolutely nothing printing to the output file. However, Java says it's been modified from an outside source. I used to be able to view the file changes right in my JGrasp IDE. Is there something obvious I'm overlooking?

Here's the code... Just in case it's my code:

```
public class ReadFile
{
static Scanner inFile;
static PrintWriter outFile;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
  String inputString;
  final String indent = "     ";
  inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("History.d1"));
  outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("History.d2"));
  inputString = indent + inFile.nextLine();
  outFile.println(inputString);

  while (inFile.hasNextLine())
  {
    inputString = inFile.nextLine();
  }

  if (inputString.length() < 1) 
  {
    outFile.print("/n");
  }
  else if (inputString.length() > 0)
  {
    inputString = indent + inputString;
  }
  outFile.println(inputString);
}
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend indenting your code.

Comment: I don't think the problem is Java, your IDE is requesting you to reload the file since its modified outside the IDE (by your program.)

Comment: I would also `close()` inFile and outFile after you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you externally modify a file that is already open in an IDE*, you will be asked to reload the file.  In Eclipse, this can be done by pressing the F5 button.  This will refresh the file display with the changes made.

You don't state in your question if the correct information is shown after you refresh the file.  I think the problem that you're having is you're confusing the real-time display of text in the console view with the file display view.

If you changed the output print operation from  `System.out.println` statement to `outFile.println`, this means the output is getting sent to the file specified, and not to the console.  If you want to verify that the output is indeed being printed, you can include `System.out.println(inputString)` before or after the `outFile.println(inputString)` statement.

Also, as mazaneicha suggested, it is a good idea to execute the `close()` method on `inFile` and `outFile` when you're done with them.  Even though the Java garbage collection will automatically close these connections, its still a good idea to get in the habit.

*works for Eclipse and Netbeans

Answer (score 0):

You need at least to flush the writer, add this at the end:

```
outFile.flush();
```

Also remember to close the streams when you are done:

```
outFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This segment of code will make the inFile reader read all the way to the end of the file, bypassing the if/else code block.  I don't think you meant to have just this one line in the while loop.

```
 while (inFile.hasNextLine())
 {
     inputString = inFile.nextLine();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The new line character is '\n', not '/n'. Here is some code that may do what you want:

```
try(BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("History.d1")); BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("History.d2"))){   
    String inputString;
    final String indent = "     ";

    while ((inputString=inFile.readLine())!=null)
    {   

        if (inputString.length() < 1)   
        {
            outFile.write("\n");
        }
        else if (inputString.length() > 0)
        {
            inputString = indent + inputString;
            outFile.write(inputString);
        }

    }   
}
```